# Can't read file using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I'm trying to read a file using Eclipse console directly via `RandomAcessFile` command. Here's my line of code where I call for this:

```
RandomAccessFile direcciones = new RandomAccessFile("direccionesRed.txt","r");
```

I'm getting an exception because Eclipse can't find the file and I need help about where to place it. I have tried it placing copies into the 'bin' folder where .classes are placed, and into the folder where .java types are placed as well, but it doesn't seem to resolve the exception.

Can I get help about where to place my txt file, or if there's other way to call my program to read my txt file?

Comment: Your code expects that a file with name `direccionesRed.txt` exists in the process's working directory. And here this is not the case. More to the point though: this is a file which, by its name, is supposed to have text in it: you should use a `Reader` and specify the correct encoding.

Comment: That was a nice way to solve it, but hopefully I could solve it too without modifying all my code! (I've tons of `RandomAcessFile` types). Thank you for your answer btw :) @fge

Answer (score 0):

In order to don't modify my full code with `Reader` type; I've solved the problem replacing the `txt` file JUST into the same folder where all the folders of the project are (it means, next to your 'bin' folder, etc). In other words, the difference between my first try and now, it's that I placed the files into the bin folder and my projects .java folders, and now they are placed just outside them.

This way, Eclipse console will read all your txt files properly.